# Salvar arquivo Excel no Python através do Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, scrapy, xls

Como faço para a minha *spider* salvar em um único arquivo XML todos os dados do Excel dos *links* que eu extraio? Ou também salvar em cada arquivo único XLS na pasta do projeto?

Parte da minha spider:

```
def parse(self, response):
    divs = response.xpath('''meu caminho html''')
    for div in divs:
        #o arquivo xls sai dessa html
        links = div.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
        yield {'Links': links,}
```

Answer (score 1):

O formato de exportação excel não é suportado, mas o scrapy suporta:

- JSON
- JSON lines
- CSV
- XML

Você pode usar o formato CSV:

```
scrawl nome_do_spider -t csv -o planilha.csv
```